# Need a "Prime Square" type of number (For my significant other)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

No this isn't for a silly math exercise, it's a relationship with a hottie I don't want to lose at stake:

I like my TV volume to be on **Perfect Squares**, but she likes her volumes on *Prime Numbers.*

Easily provable is that for $n \geq 2$, there's no such number. $n = 0$ or $1$ are not prime numbers.

Mute is our current compromise, but for some programs that's just not feasible. If you're going to say "You're crazy/she's crazy", save it: I know.

I'm willing to stretch the rules to make this work. For example, my friends surround sound is actually measured in -dB, in which case -9 db would be a perfect volume (0 + 3i), both parts of that complex number satisfy one of us.

Is there any work arounds you guys can think of? Any crazy sketchy proof of why there exists a number (preferably positive, I dont wanna buy a new speaker system) that works for us?

Please Mathematics. This girl is out of my league beautiful, and into me.

Comment: Are you asking why there are infinitely many $(a+bi)$ where $\pm (a+bi)^2$ is a square and $a$ or $b$ is prime?  Just take Pythagorean triples..

Comment: I was hoping somebody would have a clever answer that didn't involve me having to go get a new stereo

Comment: Why is it ok to consider numbers of the form $p i$ to be "prime" for $p$ prime?

Comment: Make some research on amicable numbers and twin primes then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here's a good choice:
17.

First of all, it is a prime, so she gets what she wants. And it's only 1 away from being a square, so you almost get what you want. But wait, there's more.

17 = 16+1, the sum of 2 squares

17 = 4+4+9, the sum of 3 squares

17 = 4+4+4+4+1, the sum of 5 squares

(with 2,3, and 5 being the first three primes)

17 = 17, the sum of 1 prime

17 = 2+3+5+7, the sum of 4 primes (also consecutive)

(with 1 and 4 being the first two squares)

17 a cousin prime (differs from 13 by 4) and, more important to your cause, a doubly sexy prime (11, 23).

Furthermore, 1/17 written as a decimal repeats every 16 digits, which is not only square, it's also the same square as the $n^2+1$ formulation.

I hope this can help you with your socio-audio dilemma :)

Comment: +1. $17$ also decomposes as $1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1$, another sum of a prime number of squares.

Comment: Haha, I guess you're right.

Comment: You are a champion. I had never thought of 17 as so friendly to me...she said that's always been her lucky number! It was meant to be. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should compromise, and settle on a number which is comfortably nearly prime, and/or nearly a square.

You might argue for the square of a prime (such as 4, 9, 25, ...) since those only have one prime divisor (so you get what you want, and she "nearly" does).

Or you could argue for the product of consecutive primes (such as 6, 15, 35, 77, ...) as these are in a sense "nearly" prime and "nearly" square (so neither of you get what you want).

Or, you might argue for a prime (so this *gives her what she wants*) of the form $n^2+1$ (such as 2, 5, 17, 37, 101, ...) since those differ from a square by as little as possible (it is conjectured, but unproven, that there are infinitely many such primes to choose from).

Comment: I do see myself willing to comprimise and make it work for what is conjectured to be the smallest distance from a prime.

Thank you. I'll make sure your invitation to the wedding doesn't get lost in the mail.

Answer (score 3):

Maths is not a tool invented in order to help you "get a girl".

If you are suddenly willing to accept things like $-9 = (3i)^2$ purely on the basis that $3$ is prime then why couldn't you do this before?

We have that 9 = 3^2 and $3$ is also a "complex number" containing a prime. Why is this a problem when your new rules allow it?

Comment: Because it's 0 + 3i**2. I don't get my jollys off from the 3, but the 0 (a perfect square)

Comment: "Maths is not a tool invented in order to help you get a girl". The unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics strikes again!

Comment: True, mathematics wasn't invented for that.   That's what applied math is for.

Comment: Well I do not understand the problem then. You are allowing $-9$ because it is $(3i)^2$ and $3$ is prime yet you are not allowing $9 = 3^2$. You can't change the rule AND expect the same rule to hold in the previous case!

Comment: You have compromised and said "Ok so I will allow complex number squares with prime number coefficients" but in doing this you must now allow $9$ to be a valid volume to use.

Comment: If only it were that simple...I could prove the infinitude of rep-unit primes by just saying "oh, numbers with just one $1$ digit will do and there are infinitely many of those...job done"

Comment: `Maths is not a tool invented in order to help you "get a girl".` I disagree with you on a fundamental level. Thank you for the input.

Comment: If it works then fair enough, but I doubt the original motivation was this :p. I didn't quite make my point clear before. You are prepared to get all luvvy duvvy over $-9 = (0+3i)^2$ because the $0$ is a square and the $3$ is prime. However, you are NOT willing to allow $9$ because it is NOT prime. But under your new rules you are now forced to accept it because $9 = (3+0i)^2$. So which convention is it to be?